# Why do swimmers wear headphones?

Tags: swimming

I notice that at the London Olympics several of the swimmers wore headphones as they came into the pool area. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the same reason that a number of athletes in almost every sport, and a number of officials too: they are listening to music/speech/ambient noise.

For many it is a good way of mentally preparing themselves for an event, whether to calm their mind or focus their attention or build an aggravation, depending on what they listen to and what they may have discussed with sports psychologists or other coaches.

Comment: And for the previous 15 minutes or so they have been sitting around in the ready room waiting for the final to be called onto the deck. It can get pretty boring just sitting there...